# How to keep a win32 window always on top and allow clicks in the window below it

Tags: unity-game-engine, winapi

I'm working on a training program in Unity where the user will be performing tasks.  The idea is for them to bring up an Internet Explorer window with directions and let them keep it on top while they move it to the side (not minimize it) and keep clicking in Unity.  They will only have 1 screen so they can't just move it to screen 2.

The problem being clicking in Unity makes the other window hide.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with Unity.

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413/)

Comment: If you can afford it, you are probably better off buying a web-browser asset from the asset store and integrating it into your app.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to make the IE window topmost and translucent.

But be minded allowing clicks on the windows below IE means you can't interact with IE by either mouse nor keyboard.

```
// Get IE's main HWND as ieWnd, then

LONG_PTR exStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(ieWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLongPtr(ieWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(ieWnd, 0, 127, LWA_ALPHA);
SetWindowPos(ieWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```